# New Xcode8 extension development process

Tags: swift, xcode8, xcode-extension

Recently I'm running the Xcode plugin migration to Xcode8 built in version.
But I can't find enough documentation since it's new and the resource is very rare.

Does anybody know how to publish / install / update /remove process of the new extensions?

I've try many solution but many of the users say it doesn't work.

Here is my project call Swimat - to format your swift code.

https://github.com/Jintin/Swimat/tree/extension

Thanks for any kind of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how your users can install/update/remove your extension?

If so, they just need to launch your container app.  Once they do, they'll see the extension in System Preferences (where they can also disable it if necessary), and it'll show up when they launch Xcode.

[image: System Preferences - Extensions]

Distribution of your source editor extension works just like other types of App Extensions. See: [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1)

If your users are having trouble running *any* source editor extensions, it's possible they'll need to follow a workaround from the Xcode 8 release notes:

> To use the Editor's Comment/Uncomment Selection and Add Documentation
>   commands—as well as other installed Xcode Extensions—on OS X version 10.11,
>   launch Xcode and install additional system components, then restart your
>   Mac. (26106213)"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not familiar with App extension and will study about it. ^^

Comment: @Chris Hanson I what to know if there any performance suggestion, since processing large file will hang for a while.

Comment: That would be worth asking a separate question on Stack Overflow.